# Xamarin Android Pop Page Memory leak

Tags: xamarin, memory-leaks, xamarin.android

I'm stuck with the issue: I use Xamarin Profiler for identifying memory leaks. When I push new page to Navigation, then memory usage increases, but when I pop it from Navigation, the usage is still the same. And the useage increases if I do pushing and popping for the same page for 20 and more times..

How to solve that sort of problem? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do check you don't have any event which you didn't; unsubscribe to.

don't use lamdas, all relationship should be assigned null before leaving the page

Comment: I recommend you to see this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37465850/how-to-refresh-the-one-but-last-contentpage-on-the-navigation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> When I push new page to Navigation, then memory usage increases, but when I pop it from Navigation, the usage is still the same.

It did increasing all time, but I think it's not compared with the previous snapshot, it was compared with a baseline, that's why it always positive. You could try compare these `Size Growth` value with `snapshot 1`'s value , as illustrated in the following diagram:

[image]

Some other useful link:

- [Xamarin.Forms not freeing (and so leaking) UI elements when a Page is popped](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47796408/xamarin-forms-not-freeing-and-so-leaking-ui-elements-when-a-page-is-popped)
- [Memory used by pushing a lot of pages on Xamarin.Forms' NavigationPage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31178521/memory-used-by-pushing-a-lot-of-pages-on-xamarin-forms-navigationpage)
- [xamarin.forms know memory usage both for android and ios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46530605/xamarin-forms-know-memory-usage-both-for-android-and-ios)
- [Xamarin forms profiler - what is the real memory consumption? Size Growth always positive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47685890/xamarin-forms-profiler-what-is-the-real-memory-consumption-size-growth-always/47745871#47745871)